# Not able to ping or SSH to openstack instance

Tags: ssh, ping, openstack

I have created and launched an openstack instance. I have associated key and added all SSH (22), TCP and IMCP ports accessibility. I found an IP and then i tried to ping that ip.

HOST Machine : ubuntu 14.04 instance image : Fedora 16

```
ping 10.0.0.2
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable ....
```

Also when i tried ssh with downloaded .pem file:

```
ssh -i admin.pem admin@10.0.0.2
ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.2 port 22: No route to host
```

Obviously, I get the same response when i replace instance ip with its associated floating ip. Any helps me to ping that instance and ssh.. with both instance ip and floating ip??

Answer (score 0):

Network bridge? In RHEL based hosts, you need to create bridge, so I suppose that the same is true in Ubuntu too.